# Assigning a DocuSign 'Signing Group' to an Editor (instead of a Signer)

Tags: docusignapi

I've been using the DocuSign REST API to send envelopes to signing groups for signing - all working fine.

However, I wanted to assign a Signing Group to an 'Editor' recipient, so as anyone from that Signing Group could go in and add whatever Signing recipients they deem to be necessary.

Whilst DocuSign has not error'd and has appeared to allow this, only one of the users within this Signing Group receives the email (whereas when a Signing Group is assigned to an Signer recipient, ALL users within the Signing Group receive the email).

Does anyone know why this is?

Ultimately, I want the same behaviour as if the Signing Group was assigned to a 'Singer' in the envelope, in that all users in the signing group are notified of the envelope, and any one of those users can visit the signing ceremony, and then (as an editor) add recipients etc to the envelope.

Just to confirm, I have my signing group configured in DocuSign with the default behaviour of sending notifications to each user in the signing group.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your issue is you're missing adding a recipientRole
"Editor" recipients can specify other recipients, but these should be defined explicitly as a role. You cannot add them randomly. So, similarly to how templates are defined, you have to add a recipient that has a roleName, but not an email and name. later the "editor" can fill this in. I just tested with a signing group and both of them got the email.